# Can I get a conifer to grow from a ball of roots?

Tags: roots, conifers

Is it possible to get a new conifer from a ball of roots that I planted after manhandling the removal process to get some roots out?

Example: side of part A:[image: simple root system drawing]

Answer (score 4):

No. Most conifers, once cut down, will die, so if you removed all the trunk and topgrowth, the rootball on its own is the equivalent of incipient compost. Or doomed, dead, extinct, basically, not going to grow again.

Comment: What about the bottom growth?

Comment: What bottom growth, you only mentioned a ball of roots? You'd better post a photo

Comment: rip a ball of roots off with your hand from the bottom of the plant. You now have a ball of roots, can you plant that ball for a new plant?

Comment: In that case, I refer you to my answer above, because that's what I thought you meant in the first place.

Comment: I've edited this answer to make it clearer, referring to the rootball specifically

Comment: Where is the answer edit?

Comment: +1 for Incipient compost. Conifers grow from the tip. You remove all the tips, no more growing

Comment: Since you're talking about removing the tip, how would you split a plant so you have 2?

Comment: You can't split a conifer, nor most woody based plants like shrubs. You need to take cuttings

Comment: @GardenerJ thank you! I don't know who voted my answer down prior to your plus one, but I'd really love to know why they did.....

Comment: No idea how anyone would justify a downvote - this answer is clear, correct and concise. +1 from me.